# Meta tag for site logo on WeChat boards

Tags: wechat

In order to have our logo displayed on WeChat boards in the mobile WeChat app, we currently use the following in our pages

```
<div style="display:none;"><img src="logo4wechat.png"/></div>
```

The problem is that the image loads unnecessarily if the item is accessed from outside the WeChat app.

Are there any tags for WeChat similar to Open Graph from Facebook?